# got error when run ant for lucene source code

Tags: lucene

I forked the lucene-solr from https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr.git.
Then run ant in the directory and got the following error.

> alexkkk@alexkkk-host:lucene-solr/ (master) $ ant idea                                                                 [16:44:41]
>   Buildfile: /Users/alexkkk/Projects/lucene-solr/build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /Users/alexkkk/Projects/lucene-solr/build.xml:21: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/alexkkk/Projects/lucene-solr/lucene/common-build.xml:623: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at java.util.Arrays.stream(Arrays.java:5004)
>     at java.util.stream.Stream.of(Stream.java:1000)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:267)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>     at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:545)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ChainedMapper.lambda$mapFileName$1(ChainedMapper.java:36)
>     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$1ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:80)
>     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:484)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ChainedMapper.mapFileName(ChainedMapper.java:35)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.CompositeMapper.lambda$mapFileName$0(CompositeMapper.java:32)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
>     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:545)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.util.CompositeMapper.mapFileName(CompositeMapper.java:33)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.PathConvert.execute(PathConvert.java:363)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:346)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:448)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:172)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.java:221)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:165)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:346)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:448)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:183)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:824)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:228)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:283)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/%3C1520001738599-0.post@n3.nabble.com%3E). You have to downgrade your ant from version 1.10.2 to 1.10.1 or 1.9.

If you use Mac and use homebrew to install your ant. You can install ant 1.9.

```
brew install ant@1.9
```

and then unlink version 1.10.2 and link version 1.9.

```
brew unlink ant
brew link --force ant@1.9
```

With ant 1.9, you should be able to compile Lucene.